# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined on local host

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Using Vue.Js, when I try to run on local host, I get an error of ***Cannot read property 'get' of undefined***

It is referring to my.get request. Any advice?

```
export default {
  asyncData({ $axios }) {
   return $axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
     .then(response => {
      return { posts: response.data }
    })

},
```

Comment: maybe you need to add `const $axios = require('axios');` before the export

Comment: please share the nuxt.config.js file

Comment: Apart from your `$axios` variable being undefined, you will need to call `$get` instead of `get`.

Comment: Is the `@nuxtjs/axios` package installed in your project and present in the `modules` array in the `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: Did you run `npm i` first?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

> asyncData({ $axios }) {    return
> $axios.$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
> .then(response => {
> return { posts: response.data }
> }) },

Add $get

Comment: The error message is clear: `$axios` is `undefined`. Your answer does not address the question being asked. It doesn't really matter if one calls `get` or `$get` on `undefined`. The result is the same.